# Multithread or multiprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, performance, multiprocessing

So, currently, I am using multiprocessing to run these 3 functions together.

As only tokens changes, is it recommended to switch to multi-threading? (if yes, will it really help in a performance like speed-up and I think memory will be for sure used less)

This is my code:

```
from database_function import *
from kiteconnect import KiteTicker
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import schedule
import time
from multiprocessing import Process



def tick_A():

    #credentials code here

    tokens = [x[0] for x in db_fetchquery("SELECT zerodha FROM script ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 50")] #FETCHING FIRST 50 SCRIPTS TOKEN
    #print(tokens)

    ##### TO MAKE SURE THE TASK STARTS AFTER 8:59 ONLY ###########
    t = datetime.today()
    future = datetime(t.year,t.month,t.day,8,59)
    if ((future-t).total_seconds()) < 0:
        future = datetime(t.year,t.month,t.day,t.hour,t.minute,(t.second+2))
    time.sleep((future-t).total_seconds())
    ##### TO MAKE SURE THE TASK STARTS AFTER 8:59 ONLY ###########


    def on_ticks(ws, ticks):
        global ltp
        ltp = ticks[0]["last_price"]
        for tick in ticks:
          print(f"{tick['instrument_token']}A")
          db_runquery(f'UPDATE SCRIPT SET ltp = {tick["last_price"]} WHERE zerodha = {tick["instrument_token"]}') #UPDATING LTP IN DATABASE
          #print(f"{tick['last_price']}")


    def on_connect(ws, response):
        #print(f"response from connect :: {response}")
        # Subscribe to a list of instrument_tokens (TOKENS FETCHED ABOVE WILL BE SUBSCRIBED HERE).
        # logging.debug("on connect: {}".format(response))
        ws.subscribe(tokens)
        ws.set_mode(ws.MODE_LTP,tokens) # SETTING TOKEN TO TICK MODE (LTP / FULL / QUOTE)

    kws.on_ticks = on_ticks
    kws.on_connect = on_connect
    kws.connect(threaded=True)

    #####TO STOP THE TASK AFTER 15:32 #######
    end_time = datetime(t.year,t.month,t.day,15,32)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        #time.sleep(1)
        if datetime.now() > end_time:
          break
    #####TO STOP THE TASK AFTER 15:32 #######


def tick_B():

everything remains the same only tokens value changes

    tokens = [x[0] for x in db_fetchquery("SELECT zerodha FROM script ORDER BY id ASC OFFSET (50) ROWS FETCH NEXT (50) ROWS ONLY")]


def tick_C():

everything remains the same only tokens value changes

    tokens = [x[0] for x in db_fetchquery("SELECT zerodha FROM script ORDER BY id ASC OFFSET (100) ROWS FETCH NEXT (50) ROWS ONLY")]




if __name__ == '__main__':
    def runInParallel(*fns):
      proc = []
      for fn in fns:
        p = Process(target=fn)
        p.start()
        proc.append(p)
      for p in proc:
        p.join()

    runInParallel(tick_A , tick_B , tick_C)
```

So, currently, I am using multiprocessing to run these 3 functions together.

As only tokens changes, is it recommended to switch to multi-threading? (if yes, will it really help in a performance like speed-up and I think memory will be for sure used less)

Comment: Have you profiled your code to understand what part of it is really taking too much time to get executed? Are you CPU-bounded or IO-bounded? Based on that you will decide whether to use threads, async, or multiprocessing.

Comment: @alec_djinn I think here CPU will not take many roles because I am fetching price {LTP} from the server and adding it to my database. (every second 10-20 transactions)

Comment: Then you should use asyncio

Comment: @alec_djinn getting [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68878642/await-outside-async-in-async-await-python-nested-function) while trying asyncio

Comment: that is quite vague. Please post your code and the error message

Answer (score 1):

most Python implementations do not have true multi-threading, because they use global lock (GIL). So only one thread runs at a time.
For I/O heavy applications it should not make difference. But if you need CPU heavy operations done in parallel (and I see that you use Panda - so the answer must be yes) - you will be better off staying with multi-process app.