# await outside async in async/await

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

Was using the multiprocessing process before async, to test which is faster I am trying to run the code with async, but it gives me an error saying: *'await' outside async*.

My code:

```
import asyncio
import time

async def sleep():
    print(f'Time: {time.time() - start:.2f}')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def sum(name, numbers):

    def sum_(numbers):
        total = 0
        print(f'Task {name}: Computing {total}+{number}')
        await sleep()
        total += number
        print(f'Task {name}: Sum = {total}\n')

    for number in numbers:
        sum_(numbers)

start = time.time()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [
    loop.create_task(sum("A", [1, 2])),
    loop.create_task(sum("B", [1, 2, 3])),
]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
loop.close()

end = time.time()
print(f'Time: {end-start:.2f} sec')
```

**Please note:** This is just an example of code, in original code I cannot do as per the below:

```
    for number in numbers:
        sum_(numbers)
        await sleep()
```

Testing asyncio as advised on this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68858940/multithread-or-multiprocess#comment121698913_68858940)

Comment: `sum_()` is not an async function, you can't use `await` in it. Change to `async def sum_(numbers):`

Comment: I tried by doing something: `async def on_ticks(ws, ticks): #await sleep() inside this function` and `await kws.on_ticks = on_ticks`, it gave me error: *SyntaxError: cannot assign to await expression*, [full code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68858940/multithread-or-multiprocess) @Barmar

Comment: It should be `kws.on_ticks = await on_ticks()` You use `await` to call an asynchronous function.

Comment: @Barmar this time it gave *object function can't be used in 'await' expression*, looks like asyncio cannot be used on this [question code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68858940/multithread-or-multiprocess)

Answer (score 1):

`sum_` is a separate function, as far as Python is concerned. If you want to `await` inside a function, it needs to be `async`. And if you want to call an `async` function, you need to `await` it.

```
async def sum(name, numbers):

    async def sum_(numbers): # <-- This function needs to be async
        total = 0
        print(f'Task {name}: Computing {total}+{number}')
        await sleep()
        total += number
        print(f'Task {name}: Sum = {total}\n')

    for number in numbers:
        await sum_(numbers) # <-- And we need to await it here
```

Comment: I tried by doing something: `async def on_ticks(ws, ticks): #await sleep() inside this function` and `await kws.on_ticks = on_ticks`, it gave me error: *SyntaxError: cannot assign to await expression*, [full code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68858940/multithread-or-multiprocess)

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to see what that comment has to do with this question. `await` can't be used on assignment expressions, sure, but that's not remotely what was asked here. If you have another question, consider making a separate post about it.

Comment: there's already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68858940/multithread-or-multiprocess) for it which gave me a solution to use asyncio and was doing the same. Have already mentioned in the question: *Testing asyncio as advised on this comment*